# How to copy a text and store it into a variable using Selenium? Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to copy a text from a website and store it into a variable so I can add it to a dictionary later. I wanted to know how do I accomplish it?

Here is my source code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

f = webdriver.Firefox()

f.get("http://hi.com")

g = f.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').getText()

print g
```

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750447/performing-a-copy-and-paste-with-selenium-2) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of text you need to copy from web page?

You need to locate webelement of text you need to capture and simply use getText() on it.

String text = driver.findElement(By.id("some id")).getText();

Comment: Say I want to print get the text " This Site Is Under Construction and Coming Soon." and save it into a variable, from http://hi.com. I tried the method suggested by you and it didn't work.

Comment: Try this - String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mid']/h1")).getText();

Comment: inpython = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your-xpath").text